# htaccess rewrite with multiple queries?

Tags: .htaccess

I have SEO friendly urls working ok however i've since changed my file directory and need to adjust things however I can't seem to get this to work.

Essentially i'm after the following through htaccess

```
$1.php?id=$2&subid=$3
```

and possibly more queries afterwards, any ideas?

I don't fancy listing each page but would rather do it dynamically. htaccess works for the $1.php page but I cant figure out how to add in extra $'s

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v2/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

https://steve-morris.co.uk/v2/services works but https://steve-morris.co.uk/v2/property/to-rent doesn't

essentially i'm after

```
https://steve-morris.co.uk/v2/property/to-rent
```

to link to

```
https://steve-morris.co.uk/v2/property.php?id=to-rent
```

and for

```
https://steve-morris.co.uk/v2/services/hello/this-is-a-service
```

to go to

```
https://steve-morris.co.uk/v2/services.php?id=hello&subid=this-is-a-service
```

but id like it dynamic so that I don't have to write a rewrite for each page

Comment: post example URLs and what they should map to, posting your htaccess might help

Comment: So what does `/property/to-rent` supposed to map to? `property.php?id=to-rent`?

Comment: You said you want this `$1.php?id=$2&subid=$3` So what is your `id` and `subid` in this `/v2/property/to-rent`. There is not enough info to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you should be able to just add the additional rules.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v2/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&subid=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Let me know how that works out.

Answer (score 0):

Last lines should be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&subid=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: It's because RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC] . You can try to remove them